# How to disambiguate signer types in operation json

Tags: horizon, operations, set-options, signer

The set_options operation JSON returned by Horizon does not disambiguate between `signer_keys` of different types (hash, signed txn hash, account).

```
// sha256 hash
"signer_key": "XCVKVKVKVKVKVKVKVKVKVKVKVKVKVKVKVKVKVKVKVKVKVKVKVKVKV6IF",

//  Ed25519 public key
"signer_key": "GAQUWIRXODT4OE3YE6L4NF3AYSR5ACEHPINM5S3J2F4XKH7FRZD4NDW2",

// Pre-authorized txn hash
"signer_key": "TCPY4QKJLOI6XLFFU7EN6FO7Y5PEFWBP6V4SXXXSQMRW2OYE27KGH4ZP",
```

We know that any value that doesn't start with `G` cannot be a public key. But can we infer anything else?

XDR deserialisation disambiguates this enumeration. Can the JSON API do the same?

Comment: Enhancement raised https://github.com/stellar/horizon/issues/430

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the JSON API does not disambiguate like SDR deserialization does.  Hopefully, the JSON API will be able to disambiguate different signature types in the future.